# VPN protocol support

Tags: vpn

What are the types of VPN protocols that are supported by Ubuntu desktop 14.04 LTS? I only see PPTP. Are there any other VPN protocol built into Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Answer (score 1):

Without installation of **any** additional software, PPTP is the only available option in Ubuntu. However, you can also install plug-ins for Ubuntu's Network Manager for other types of vpn, for example:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn
sudo apt-get install network-manager-vpnc
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openconnect
```

For the `openvpn`, `vpnc`, and `openconnect` protocols, respectively. After those are installed, you can configure the VPNs in your network manager the same way you can with PPTP.

Comment: Thanks. I thought Ubuntu supported more built in VPN clients

Answer (score 0):

Far as i know there are `Cisco VPN` and `OpenVPN`

If you want these you need to install them to network-manager

**OpenVPN**

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn
```

**Cisco VPN**

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-vpnc
```

You will need to restart network-manager to apply changes

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

1. Click on the network-manager in the system tray
2. Choose VPN Connections -> Configure VPN
3. Select what VPN connection you want then click <kbd>Create...</kbd>

[image]

[VPN - Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VPN)